# Верстка блока с видео в рамке из png

Tags: вёрстка, iframe, адаптивная-верстка, responsive

Всем добрый вечер, нужно сделать видео на сайте обрамленное рамкой в моем случае эта рамка png планшета с вырезанным дисплеем (по задумке якобы видео играет из планшета). Взял блок задал ему ширину, высоту и поставил на background эту самую рамку задал падинги чтобы видео смотрелось якобы в экране и не выходило за его рамки, и внутрь вставил iframe с самим видео, но когда начал адаптивить "это" началась боль на каждом разрешении мне приходится менять ширину с высотой как рамки так и самого iframe, может кто то уже занимался подобным подскажите как лучше делать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так: задать `iframe` 100%,  ширину сделать `padding` на ширину рамки планшета, и обязательно `box-sizing:border-box`,  а в адаптиве маштабируйте только сам блок с с фоном планшета.